# Selenium WebDriver setting ImplicitlyWait does nothing

Tags: java, firefox, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Here is the entirety of my test class in Java, minus imports.

```
public class GoogleTest {

private WebDriver driver;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
}

@Test
public void testGoogleTest() throws Exception {
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
    driver.findElement(By.id("I don't exist"));
}

@After
public void tearDown() throws Exception {
    driver.quit();
    }
}
```

From my understanding, the implicitlyWait command should make the test error out with "ElementNotFound" after 5 seconds. This doesn't happen. It does open an FF window, goes to google and then sits there forever. If I close the browser window, it will throw an UnreachableBrowser exception (as I would expect). 
I've tried playing around with different time units, but it made no difference.
I'm using Selenium 2.25.

Comment: I see what you are asking now.  I am also very interested in the solution to this issue.   I will test it later and if I discover anything I will post here.

Comment: I just tried updating to the latest version, and it seems to be working now, as per amey's suggestion

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems to be a bug with Selenium `2.25` and Selenium `2.26`, so try updating to `2.27`

Comment: I tested the above code with Junit 4.11 and Selenium 2.28 and it works fine, just as expected.