# WebDriver Selenium browse file Java

Tags: java, eclipse, junit, webdriver

Can't browse file using webdriver.

```
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.findElement(By.id("1434461513889_57_7_input.file")).sendKeys("C:\\PDF_V1_COL88810_6L_Frangipani_TL_Fr_P1211089.pdf");
```

Have this error:

> NoSuchElementException: Unnable to locate element: {"method":"id","selector":"BatchUploadPlugin_57_fileupload"}

[HTML code](http://prntscr.com/7hx49e)

Comment: `NoSuchElementException` does not come from your code snippet. So you are looking for an element with id `BatchUploadPlugin_57_fileupload` somewhere on your code even before the wait. I believe you are looking for that element even before the DOM has loaded. Update the question with the full code snippet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot you have given, I can see the **concerned element is in an iframe.**

***(Check the second bar in the developer tools below the bar containing: Inspector, Console,etc. You will note the iframe#iframe_1434526152814_57_7. ).***

Hence, you weren't able to send the path to it.

In order to send the path for upload, **you need to switch to the frame first and then send the path to the element "Browse" for upload.**

For **switching frame**, you can use the below code *(**The frame id that I can see from the screenshot, is `iframe_1434526152814_57_7` which I can safely presume to be dynamic and can't use as ID of the frame to switch-to. So, I am assuming there is only 1 frame in the page, hence the code.**)*:

```
driver.switchTo().frame(0);
```

Then, **send the path to the element** using the below code:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='userfile']")).sendKeys("C:\\PDF_V1_COL88810_6L_Frangipani_TL_Fr_P1211089.pdf");
```

Comment: Glad it worked out for you.. Please accept the answer too. It will help others facing similar problem,  to check it out directly.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Kindly do in below way :

```
driver.findElement(By.id("1434461513889_57_7_input")).sendKeys("C:\\PDF_V1_COL88810_6L_Frangipani_TL_Fr_P1211089.pdf");
```

**.File** element should not be there in id.

Comment: sorry, there wasn't I was just testing, because I don't knew what is the problem there. So may be you have any idea what it can be, why it's not working?

Comment: No( Have an error - "NoSuchElementException: Unnable to locate element: ..."

Comment: I see , you please remove implicit wait from your code which is at just above your file browse code. and add `thread.sleep(10000)`.

Comment: Did it, but have the same error, didn't help. I don't even know what it can be

Comment: I know why it's not working, It's because my button is in unvisible element:
http://prntscr.com/7idgkg
I think It's because of this, but how to make it visible?

Comment: then selenium should fire exception `Element not Visible`

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert in selenium, but looks like the snippet of the code you have posted is not able to throw this exception. As it searches for `BatchUploadPlugin_57_fileupload`, which is form id. And your code is searching for an input, which id is `1434461513889_57_7_input`.

Also what I've figured out is that `driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` may not work as expected for [these](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14386470/selenium-webdriver-setting-implicitlywait-does-nothing) developers. Try to replace it with `Thread.sleep(3000);`. I know that thread sleep is not recommended for selenium, but just to test.

Comment: just have an error after replaced with "Thread.sleep(3000)" "NoSuchElementException: Unnable to locate element: ..."

Answer (score 0):

Try below code..
you need to pass upload textbox webelement and upload button webelement..

```
public void UploadFile(By locatorUpload, By locatorButton, String filePath){

        driver.findElement(locatorUpload).sendKeys(filePath);
        waitForElementClickable(driver, locatorButton, 4);
        driver.findElement(locatorButton).click();

    }

public void waitForElementClickable(WebDriver driver, By locator, Integer timeoutInSeconds){
    WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, timeoutInSeconds);
    wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(locator));
}
```

Comment: what is the difference between locatorUpload and locatorButton? I have just one button on the form.
And have an error on "waitForElementClickable" - undefined method

Comment: I've updated waitForElementClickable() function as well. Is your webpage has browse button to locator file? if yes, pass the element to locatorUpload para and pass upload button element to  locatorButton

Comment: I see thank you. But what I should assigned to locatorUpload and locatorButton? I have ID for button it's "1434461513889_57_7_input", and I don't get what will be for locatorUpload?
http://prntscr.com/7hx49e

Answer (score -1):

For Dealing with Native Elements, Why can't you try out Sikuli Integration with Selenium scripts.
You can refer to this link for more details.
http://selenium-suresh.blogspot.in/2014/01/sikuli-automation-tool-integration-with.html